# PySpark RDD Mapping Maps Multiple Rows Together

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do i force RDD MAP to iterate through each row rather than sometimes iterating through two rows at a given time?

```
book = []

def customer_order_agg(row):
   book.append(row['order_number'])
   return book

sample2 = df.rdd.map(customer_order_agg)
print(sample2.take(5))
```

The results I get is this

```
[[721], [721, 722, 723], [721, 722, 723], [721, 722, 723, 724, 725], [721, 722, 723, 724, 725]]
```

What i expect is this

```
[[721], [721, 722], [721, 722, 723], [721, 722, 723, 724], [721, 722, 723, 724, 725]]
```

My df contents

```
2019-02-27 01:21:49.839392|1|1|136.14|20000.0|0.0|20000.0|0|721|retretre|               
2019-02-27 01:21:49.839392|1|1|135.0|3000.0|0.0|3000.0|0|722|tetr|                
2019-02-27 01:21:49.839392|1|1|135.0|70000.0|0.0|70000.0|0|723|retete|                 
2019-02-27 01:21:49.839392|1|1|135.0|1000.0|0.0|1000.0|0|724|etrertert|                 
2019-02-27 01:21:49.839392|1|1|135.0|200000.0|0.0|200000.0|0|725|00tertL|
```

Comment: if I understand well what you're trying to do, you should use a `collect_list` with a window.

Comment: I could, but for every row i iterate through i want to access the an object that will contain not just the above numbers but something like a json and i want to add / delete to this object based on some criteria. Can you do this with collect list for this?

Comment: what's in `df`?

Comment: added df contents above

Comment: @SecretAgent, I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964179/pyspark-mapping-multiple-variables thanks in advance!